# How to specify an beginTime for an animation by using CFTimeInterval?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

For my understanding, beginTime can be used to say "hey, start at exactly 12:00 'o clock". But how would I tell this with an CFTimeInterval type? I thought that this one is nothing more than a kind of "float" value to specify seconds.

Or what else would be then the difference to the timeOffset property that is specified in CAMediaTiming protocol?

Answer (score 59):

What I missed in the docs: beginTime is in "core animation absolute time" so you've to get the current time and specify your offset from that:

```
// Start in 5 seconds
theAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5;
```

Comment: beginTime is specified in parent time space, not relative to absolute time.

Comment: @an0, obviously, in my case, the parent time space is identical to CACurrentMediaTime(), so it works just fine. How would you refer to the parent time space?

Comment: We should use current time in layer time space — parent time space of animation directly added to layer — as the base. If layer's beginTime is set to non-zero, your code won't work. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 26):

You first need to convert to the layer's *timespace* like so:

```
let currentLayerTime = myLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
```

Then you can set the `beginTime` relative to the layer's now time. For instance, to make an animation begin in 2s:

```
myAnimation.beginTime = currentLayerTime + 2
```

You'll also likely want to set the `fillMode` to `.backwards`, so that you can set the final property value before you add the animation:

```
myAnimation.fillMode = .backwards
myLayer.someProperty = someFinalValue
myLayer.addAnimation(myAnimation, forKey: "myAnimationName")
```

Comment: Amazing, `let currentLayerTime = myLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)` is so important, because `CACurrentMediaTime()` maybe not so precise

Answer (score 17):

No, that is not what beginTime does. It specifies a relative start time from its parent animation (by default multiple animations in a group all fire at once).

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/CAMediaTiming/beginTime):

> Specifies the begin time of the
>   receiver in relation to its parent
>   object, if applicable.

timeOffset causes it to start animating at the frame it would be at at the offSet time, and when it reaches the end it loops around. In other words, imagine A,B,C,D,E are frames of animation this is what happends in various cases if you set beginTime or timeOffset to a value equal to when you hit frame C in the normal case.

```
Normal      |A->B->C->D->E
beginTime:  |      A->B->C->D->E
timeOffset: |C->D->E->A->B
```

Comment: Just setting timeOffset doesn't delay the animation and change the initial time.  Your line for 'timeOffset' is really what would happen is you set 'timeOffset' and 'beginTime'...right?

Comment: Louis, do you know whether there is a way to just run an animation like: Partial: | -  -  A->B->C, so basically the same as the beginTime case you mentioned but have it stop when it gets to the end  instead of having it loop around?

Comment: Worked like charm @LouisGerbarg . Thanks

Answer (score 16):

I think the documentation of CAMediaTiming Protocol is very bad. [Time Warp in Animation](http://wangling.me/2011/06/time-warp-in-animation/) is a thorough explanation(re-documentation) of all properties of CAMediaTiming Protocol.