# CABasicAnimation on CATextLayer fontSize not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to make a pulsing animation on a `CATextLayer` when the user enters more characters in a `UITextView` than the maximum allowed.

The code runs but the animation does not happen.

```
public partial class MyViewController : UIViewController, IUITextViewDelegate
{
   const int MAX_COMMENTS_CHARS = 500;
   CATextLayer charsLeftTextLayer;

   public override void ViewDidLoad()
   {
      base.ViewDidLoad();

      charsLeftTextLayer = new CATextLayer();
      var uiFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12);
      charsLeftTextLayer.ContentsScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale; //stops text appearing blurry
      charsLeftTextLayer.SetFont(uiFont.Name);
      charsLeftTextLayer.FontSize = 12;
      charsLeftTextLayer.String = $"{MAX_COMMENTS_CHARS} chars left";
      charsLeftTextLayer.ForegroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
      charsLeftTextLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
      charsLeftTextLayer.Frame = new CGRect(582, 153, 99, 21);

      View.Layer.AddSublayer(charsLeftTextLayer);
   }

   private void PulseCharsLeft()
    {
        var animation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("fontSize");

        animation.SetFrom(NSNumber.FromNInt(12));
        animation.SetTo(NSNumber.FromNInt(16));
        animation.Duration = 1.0;
        animation.BeginTime = 0.01;
        animation.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.Linear);
        animation.AutoReverses = true;

        charsLeftTextLayer.AddAnimation(animation, null);
    }

    #region UITextView delegates

    [Export("textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:")]
    public bool ShouldChangeText(UITextView textView, NSRange range, string text)
    {       
        if (textView.Text.Length + text.Length > MAX_COMMENTS_CHARS)
        {
            PulseCharsLeft();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I'll accept answers in C#, Swift or Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `animation.BeginTime = 0.01;` in method `PulseCharsLeft()` and then it will work.

It should look like:

```
private void PulseCharsLeft()
{
    var animation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("fontSize");

    animation.SetFrom(NSNumber.FromNInt(12));
    animation.SetTo(NSNumber.FromNInt(16));
    animation.Duration = 1.0;
    //animation.BeginTime = 10;
    animation.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.Linear);
    animation.AutoReverses = true;

    charsLeftTextLayer.AddAnimation(animation, "basic");

}
```

`BeginTime` specifies a relative start time from its parent animation (by default multiple animations in a group all fire at once).

From the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427654-begintime?language=objc):

> Specifies the begin time of the receiver in relation to its parent
>   object, if applicable.

You can look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166405/how-to-specify-an-begintime-for-an-animation-by-using-cftimeinterval/1168710#1168710) to learn more about `BeginTime`.

BTW, in the question, your `charsLeftTextLayer.Frame = new CGRect(582, 153, 99, 21);`, is the `x`(582) too big for you to test?

I changed it into a small value and add a textView to test it.

```
    charsLeftTextLayer.Frame = new CGRect(82, 153, 99, 21);
```

Also I changed the `MAX_COMMENTS_CHARS` to 10 and it is easier to test.

Comment: Thanks Jack, btw, 582 is x co-ordinate not width :)